# How can I open an access database in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, connection, database-connection

I'm trying to open an access database with the extension .accdb so I can read some information from this database. I have no problem doing this, if I use the wizard:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

However when try to use code to do this I always get an exception when I try to connect:
[image]

[image]

From debugging I understood that the exception comes from not having opened the connection. So I open the connection but the the database comes as empty:

[image]

I have looked around stack overflow and tried to apply many of the answers to similar questions but they haven't worked. In theory if I can connect through the wizard I should also be able to connect through OleDBConnection object in C#. How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure but how about using `Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;`?

Comment: have you tried to do a simple sql request to it? using `OleDbDataReader`?

Comment: Please post the code where you instantiate the DataAdapter and set its query string.

Comment: That doesn't work for the new extension of access databases .accdb. You have to use 12.0.

Comment: @JohnWu I have updated my question.

Comment: @j0ey_wh I get an exception because it can't find the table. Which is comprehensible since the database comes as "".

Comment: @JoãoPaiva database is of type string so i guess you just need to give it the name of the database that you have in your access file
`myAccessConnection.Database = "yourDataBaseName"`

Comment: @j0ey_wh I can't do that because that property is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. My table name had a space between "Tab_Project Data" and because I didn't use [] it was looking for a table named "Tab_Project" which it couldn't find. So I just had to put "[Tab_Project Data]" inside my query and now it works.